# How to download data from KEGG database?

Tags: python-3.x, biopython

I am currently working on extracting data from KEGG database for a prediction study. It would be helpful to know that any existing library already present to extract the data.

Comment: https://biopython.org/docs/1.76/api/Bio.KEGG.REST.html